# comma operator in c++

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, output

Below is the code.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class x {
    int a;
public :
    x(int t=2):a(t) {}
    void print (){
        cout <<"value is "<<a;
    }
    x& operator,(x&a){
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(){
    x a(1),b(2),c(3),d(4);
    x t=(a,b,c,d);
    t.print();
    return 0;
}
```

**output** `value is 1`
please explain why the value is not 4 in this line x t=(a,b,c,d);

Comment: C'mon, you've been here long enough to know how to format code...

Comment: please let me know how to do it..

Comment: @akash I've updated the formatting.  You can use the 'edit' option to see the current content or click on the 'edited [time]' link to see the diffs.  Or try editing yourself and use the '{ }' icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x t = (a,b,c,d);
```

No matter what order this expression is evaluated in, the left-most operand will always be returned because `this` in your `x& operator , (x &instance)` refers to the left operand while `instance` refers to the right.

It is thus returning `a` and you are getting a printed value of `1`.

If you didn't overload the comma operator, you may get `4` because an expression like `(a, b, c)` will return the right-most operand.